# Compound Statement unable to change the delimiter

Tags: sql, db2

I am attempting to run a simple compound statement within the Query Editor of DB Solo 4.2.2

It appears I am unable to properly change the end of line delimiter. I am using DB2. Here is a simple example that gives the error:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE id INT;
SET id = 10;

END @

--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

Error is:
An unexpected token "INT" was found following "N ATOMIC  DECLARE id". Expected tokens may include: "END-OF-STATEMENT"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

DB2 only allows the semicolon to be used as a delimiter in Compound SQL.  The syntax you are using appears to only be valid when using the [`db2batch`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002043.html) utility (which comes with DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows).

Here is some relevant information from the [Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_sqlprocedurebody.htm) (this is from the z/OS IC):

> **How to code multiple statements in an SQL procedure**
>
> Use a semicolon
>   character to separate SQL statements within an SQL procedure.
>
> The procedure body has no terminating character. Therefore, if the
>   procedure contains only one statement, you do not need to put a
>   semicolon after that statement. If the procedure consists of a set of
>   nested statements, you do not need to put a semicolon after the
>   outermost statement.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a way for me to declare variables to use without creating a stored procedure and instead just using the BEGIN and END tags?

Comment: To clarify, the syntax (`--#SET TERMINATOR `) is supported by the DB2 Command Line Processor.